# jQuery works in JSFiddle but not local RoR environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Currently I have two JavaScript functions. The "Check All" function works perfectly in both JSFiddle and local environment `(http://0.0.0.0:3000)`. However, "Select Animal" or a function that only selects specific options in a form only works in JSFiddle but not in local envirobment. I wonder what is causing this issue.

Here are the codes inside my "_form.html.erb":

```
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
          checked = false;
          function checkedAll () {
            if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}
            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myform').elements.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById('myform').elements[i].checked = checked;
        }
          }
    </script>

    <body>
        <form id="myform">
        Foo1<input type="checkbox" name="foo1"/>
        Bar2<input type="checkbox" name="bar2"/>
        Rah3<input type="checkbox" name="rah3"/>
        Check all: <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll()'>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
        function checkAnimal () {
            var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
            $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked"));
                     }   
    </script>

    <body>
        <form id='list'><br>
        1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
        2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
        3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
        4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
        5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
        CheckAnimal<input type='checkbox' ID="checkAnimalCheckbox" name='checkthese' onclick='checkAnimal()'><br>
        </form>
   </body>
```

EDIT:

I've changed my codes to the following:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script language='JavaScript'>
  checked = false;
  function checkedAll () {
    if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myform').elements.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('myform').elements[i].checked = checked;
}
  }
</script>

<script language='JavaScript'>
    function checkAnimal () {
        var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
        $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked"));

             }   
</script>

<body>

<form id="myform">
Foo1<input type="checkbox" name="foo1"/>
Bar2<input type="checkbox" name="bar2"/>
Rah3<input type="checkbox" name="rah3"/>
Check all: <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll()'>
</form>

<form id='list'><br>
1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
CheckAnimal<input type='checkbox' ID="checkAnimalCheckbox" name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal()'><br>
</form>

</body>
```

And "Check All" function works very well, and "Check Animal" still doesn't work :/

SECOND EDIT:

I also tried removing head tads around jquery.min.js and the body tags around the forms, and it gives the same result. Check All works and Check Animal doesn't.

THIRD EDIT:

Revised codes after reading you guys' suggestions. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.. Very interesting!

```
    <head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
      checked = false;
      function checkedAll () {
        if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myform').elements.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('myform').elements[i].checked = checked;
      }
      }
    </script>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
        $(function() {
        function checkAnimal () {
        var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
        $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked"));
        }
        }); 
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="myform">
    Foo1<input type="checkbox" name="foo1"/>
    Bar2<input type="checkbox" name="bar2"/>
    Rah3<input type="checkbox" name="rah3"/>
    Check all: <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll()'>
    </form>

    <form id='list'><br>
    1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
    2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
    3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
    4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
    5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
    CheckAnimal<input type='checkbox' ID="checkAnimalCheckbox" name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal()'><br>
    </form>

   </body>
```

EDIT 4:

I've removed `$(function() {` around "Check Animal" function after Firebug shows "Check Animal" is not defined. And now the new error is:

```
TypeError: $(...).find is not a function

...lue=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox...
```

The new "Check Animal" code is simply reversed back to the original code:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function checkAnimal() {
var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
$("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Why is your script tage between head and body sections? and multiple head and body section in your html?

Comment: I don't see Select Animal anywhere in your code.

Comment: You have two body tag, two form in your solution. That's not a good idea!

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, I meant "checkAnimal()". It is the second JavaScript inside the code.

Comment: I suspect it's working in jsfiddle because it removes your `<body>` and `<head>` tags and inserts the codes in its own head and body sections.

Comment: @PSL: I'm very new to web dev, so I use different head/body to keep track of my codes. Is that the reason why the second JavaScript doesn't work? And should I put both script tags before the first body?

Comment: @Barmar: OK! Let me try that and I'll report back :)

Comment: Everything should be either in the `<head>` or `<body>` section of the file, and there should only be one of each of these. You shouldn't have anything between `</head>` and `<body>`.

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript console for errors when it's not working?

Comment: Yes, try place your script on the head and it should work...

Comment: Hello! I've updated the codes accordingly, but it still doesn't work :/ I wonder why..Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console.log?  Is jquery loading twice? Anything else to help you debug?

Comment: OK. I will use firebug to check for these possible culprits. Will report shortly. Thank you!

Comment: I found these two warnings: 1. SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
 
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/licens ///// 2. Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.
 
src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse; /// Not sure if they are helpful in resolving the issue. Thank you all!

Comment: Update: Found an error! Firebug says "checkAnimal" is not defined :)

Comment: Update Again: I removed "$(function() {" around checkAnimal, and the new error is: TypeError: $(...).find is not a function ...lue=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox...

Comment: I found the solution! The trick is to replace all "$" in function "checkAnimal" to "jQuery". Now the code works perfectly :) Thank you very much for all the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Thank you so much for all of your help. Without you, I wouldn't have figured this out.

The solution is changing "$" in the code to "jQuery" for function "checkAnimal" as shown below:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
                function checkAnimal () {
                var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
                jQuery("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", jQuery("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked"));

                 } 
</script>
```

Happy Holidays, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  function checkAnimal () {
    var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
    $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", $("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello there, I've used your code instead, but local environment is very stubborn! Please kindly check my revised code above :)